# TDD with Test::Unit on Rails? View/Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I'm wondering how views, integration gets tested using the vanilla rails test stack.

I already know Cucumber/RSpec but want a simpler, faster, more productive testing solution and I think Test::Unit offers that.

Answer (score 3):

For views: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views

For integration: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing

The official guides are your best bet for the latest version of Test::Unit.

Also note the "Guides Index" link [on the top of that page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html), which gives you all the links to the latest, official online guides.